# Javascript function not working when performing actions on a different HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that if clicked calls a js function that should change the current page and display a simple hello world message, but all that happens is that the page gets changed but nothing is being displayed

Atalanta.html

```
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick = "Atalanta1();">Read More </button>
```

Article.html

```
<div id = "NewsArticle">

</div>
```

javascript file

```
function Atalanta1() {
    document.location.href = "../Article.html";
    var article = document.querySelector("#NewsArticle");
    var title = "";

    title += "<h2>" + "Hello World" + "</h2>";

    article.innerHTML = title;
}
```

Comment: You can't control the new page with JS from the old page.

Comment: Is there any other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply use an `<a>` tag to link to next page?

Answer (score 0):

Options: -

a) Shift all the 4 statements after the redirect to the onload event
   of the new page.

b) Pass parameters to new page in URL

c) Pass parameters in Local Storage

d) Use an iframe

Answer (score 0):

Change your button to :

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="Article.html">Read More </a>
```

On Article.html add this script :

```
window.onload = function() {
    var title = "";
    var article = document.querySelector("#NewsArticle");

    title += "<h2>" + "Hello World" + "</h2>";

    article.innerHTML = title;
}
```